# Why do I experience an "invalid token structure", but when I re-run the application the error disappears

Tags: android, kotlin, authentication, token

Why do I experience an "invalid token structure" error when `getStory` in `MainActivity` is called, but when I re-run the application the error disappears?

So my goal is to display a list of stories when `GetStory` is called, but when the invalid token appears, the story list structure does not appear.

Strangely this problem disappeared when I re-run the application.

I want the application to run well without re-run.

So here is my code that might be related to the problem, you can check my project on GitHub (https://github.com/Bangkit-Submitted-Assignment/4_AndroidIntermediate_JeffrySusilo/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/dicoding/picodiploma/loginwithanimation):

What I have just tried is checking whether the token has been saved properly and if I look at the log the token has been saved.

There is a possibility that the problem is not empty tokens.

Comment: The link to the code returns a 404, could you update the post?